# Is this Hufflepuff plural or singular?

Tags: plural-forms, singular

> "And what are Slytherin and Hufflepuff?" 
>     "School houses. **There's four**. Everyone says **Hufflepuff are a lot o' duffers**, but --" 
>     "I bet I'm in Hufflepuff" said Harry gloomily. 
>   (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

I bet there should be *are* in *there’s four*, but I’m not quite sure if there be *is* or *are* in *Hufflepuff are a lot o’ duffers*. (I guess it may depends on which is the head of *a lot o’ duffers*: *lot* or *duffers*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part reads "There's four" because that's how Hogwarts-aged kids talk. "There are four" may be more grammatically correct, but it wouldn't have made for a better book.

As for the second part, I think that's just some implied words. I believe the speaker really means:

> Everyone says [those in] Hufflepuff are a lot o' duffers, but...

or

> Everyone says [those assigned to] Hufflepuff are a lot o' duffers, but --

Comment: Don't forget that in BrE [collective nouns take plural verb forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_American_and_British_English#Formal_and_notional_agreement).

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung - I suspect your answer is more correct than mine. Maybe you should elaborate some more in an answer to this question.

Comment: I think that's the only piece yours needs. It all gets a bit squidgy with fictional sprogs a-bandy—as you've rightly said—so I can't be bothered to lay down the law anyway.